# Book suggestions on classic control

Tags: book-recommendation, control-theory

I am looking for suggestions about introductory books on classic control theory. Books that begin by trying to develop intuition to the reader using basic principles of the notion of control and investigate a logical flow of thoughts with the mistakes that an inexperienced student might make, until the establishment of the formal mathematical theory.
Would you please have any such suggestions to make?

Answer (score 1):

Classical control is a stable theory and most popular textbooks are similar.

Feedback systems : an introduction for scientists and engineers - Karl J Åström; Richard M Murray is a good text, perhaps making a bigger effort to be intuitive to non-specialists.

Modern Control Engineering by Katsuhiko Ogata is also a good choice, with a more standard treatment. The older editions are no worse than the new ones, and arguably have some advantages.

Feedback Control of Dynamic Systems, by G. F. Franklin, J. D. Powell and A. Emami–Naeini gets into more detail about the frequency-domain design techniques. I think it's an excellent reference.

Other sources exist, and each one has its fans, but you cannot go wrong with any of the 3 above.

Let me add The Art of Control Engineering, by Ken  Dutton, Steve  Thompson, and Bill Barraclough. Perhaps less frequently adopted than the 3 above, but at points makes a bigger effort to emphasize the intuition. Altogether however the 4 texts are not fundamentally distinct.